# When can callee of Python call expression be a call expression?

Tags: python, parsing

[The grammar for a call expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) says that the callee can itself be a call expression. I can't think of an example of when this would be the case. Can anyone provide a short sample showing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What, exactly, are you referring to in the docs? Can you quote the part? I think youa re referring to something like `foo()()` where the callee is `foo()` which is itself a call expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f():
    return g
def g():
    return 1
print(f()())
```

This prints `1`. `f()` is the callee in `f()()`.

Answer (score 0):

A call is an expression; it is listed in the Expressions reference documentation. If it was a statement, you could not use it as part of an expression; statements can contain expressions, but not the other way around. That would be a syntax error.

As an example, return expression is a statement; it uses expressions to determine it's behaviour; the result of the expression is what the current function returns. You can use a call as part of that expression:

```
return some_function()
```

You cannot, however, use return as part of a call:

```
some_function(return)
```

That would be a syntax error.

It is the `return` that 'does something'; it ends the function and returns the result of the expression. It's not the expression itself that makes the function return.

If a python call was not an expression, you'd never be able to mix calls and other expression atoms into more complex expressions.